# Automated UEFI install not working (ubuntu desktop)

Tags: uefi, preseed

I wanted to create a UEFI bootable usb-stick/sd-card that I can use for an unattended install of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04

Steps taken:

- unpacked iso file
- copy preseed file to root of unpacked directory
- modified boot/grub/grub.cfg as followed:

  if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
      set gfxmode=auto
      insmod efi_gop
      insmod efi_uga
      insmod gfxterm
      terminal_output gfxterm
  fi

  set menu_color_normal=white/black
  set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

  menuentry "Install Ubuntu (automated)" {
      set gfxpayload=keep
      linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/ks.preseed auto=true priority=critical debian-installer/locale=en_US keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=be ubiquity/reboot=true languagechooser/language-name=English countrychooser/shortlist=BE localechooser/supported-locales=en_US.UTF-8 boot=casper automatic-ubiquity noprompt noshell ---
      initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
  }

Then I prepared the installation media:

- created GPT partition table on sd-card
- created fat32 partition
- copied unpacked iso folder to this partition

When I boot up the machine with the sd card, the grub installer pops up and I select the "Install Ubuntu (automated)" option. The installer starts, but then I get dropped in a busybox shell (initramfs).

The following error is displayed:

```
"Unable to find a medium containing a live file system"
```

This makes sense, there is no live system. My point is to install a system.

How can I talk some sense into Ubuntu and make it start the installation with the configured preseed file?

Comment: Honestly, never before I read about such complicated method. You want a live/installation media therefore use MKUSB or `dd` or other tools. Boot from it, install, done.

Comment: The key here is AUTOMATED INSTALL. I need to modify the final iso so it includes the preseed file, and it should start this automated install as soon as it boots. This is a common scenario in an enterprise environment where automated provisioning is required.